# LINQ Accses To Log in

Tags: c#, linq

I'm try using LINQ for logging into my website. When I try to login, he just reload and cannot response anything.

This my code :

```
public partial class Log_in : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ActiveLink()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.ToString().ToLower().Contains("username"))
        {
            username.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
    }

    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
        con.Open();
        String usernames = username.Text;
        String passwords = password.Text;
        DataClasses1DataContext daneden = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var user = (from s in daneden.logins
                    where s.username == usernames && s.passwords == passwords
                    select s);

        if (user != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            usernameerror.Text = "Error!";
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the submit button linked in the aspx page? Are you seeing the error inside usernameerror element? I would say, if you don't get redirected, and you don't see an error, then the event isn't being called? Could it be that your About.aspx sends you back to the login page, because it doesn't see the logged in session of the user? You could also compare the string using `string.Equals(s.username, usernames, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` in case you want allow for case insensitivity

Comment: yes, i don't see anything about error and response. he just reload without result..
i have not made a session.. whether its problem?

Comment: Could you add your aspx contents into your question? Or at least, the  code that has to do with your login form?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var user = (from s in daneden.logins
                where s.username == usernames && s.passwords == passwords
                select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

alternately:

```
 var user = daneden.logins
        .FirstOrDefault(s=> s.username == usernames && s.passwords == passwords);
```

Comment: he still a same. whether Response.Redirect which wrong? huh i'm really confused..